# Is Retrofit Reactor Adapter making calls nonblocking?

Tags: spring-boot, retrofit2, okhttp, nonblocking, reactor

I'm using Retrofit with Reactor Adapter on a server. I thought that it allows me to make my calls unblocking by simple using `Mono` for retrofit and exposing it to Spring Boot as `Mono` as well (all operations in between are reactive).

However I noticed that when I try to run a few requests to an another service, that has some long operations inside (taking a few seconds), my service looks like it's blocking some thread, as when making several quick calls in proper configuration it can cause restarting my service (which is supposed to only wait for another service response, and data set it receives is small). Also some tracking tools make me think that my threads are busy when waiting for the response.

I tried to find some docs about that, and looked a bit into OkHttp and Okio code, and I couldn't find any part that could make it non blocking, and what's more it looked like it would be blocking.

Is there something I might miss in my retrofit configuration that could make my calls non blocking, or maybe someone is aware there is no way to make retrofit work this way?  Or simply am I misinterpreting some data and it does should be non blocking by default?

I add to my Retrofit builder such setup method to enable Reactor:

```
addCallAdapterFactory(ReactorCallAdapterFactory.create())
```

Answer (score 2):

OkHttp follows a roughly thread per connection model.  So with a HTTP/2 server a single connection can support a variable number of requests with a fixed set of pooled connections and threads.

call.execute() will be blocking.

call.enqueue(...) will be non blocking but is using threads internally, and reading from the socket in blocking mode.  This is hidden from clients, but OkHttp does not use Java NIO.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Would you be able to suggest some alternative, which would unlock threads for the time of waiting for the response. 
As far as I have checked Okio opens a stream and just waits, while another solution would be to firstly check if there is some data in the stream, and if it's not then wait without blocking, so it seems it should be possible to have such solution. 
Btw. I don't really understand what is the profit of that `non blocking` architecture then, other than that it's easy to run to calls in parallel...

Comment: I wouldn't want to give advice outside of a concrete problem.  If you have kotlin coroutines or reactive streams based architecture, then generally you can probably get by with OkHttp and call.enqueue.  Schedulers.IO is effectively the same approach, assign a thread to sit idle waiting for response from a network.

Depending on your workload you may be able to scale to multiples more connections with a limited number of threads with a finely tuned Netty based solution.  For typical mobile or a relatively calm internal server, the simplicity of OkHttp model is probably a good tradeoff.

Comment: But actually that's the problem, reactor is just RX solution for Spring, and it looks that even if I use it, thread is busy. So basically the only thing RX does is that it switches between threads, so basically when you use RX Single and think it will make your code nonblocking, in fact it's just synchronous blocking call, because of OkHttp implementation... 
The only profit that RX or coroutines give in Retrofit is nicer handling of parallel calls + switching main/network thread for Android. But thread is always busy when waiting for response.